# Worpdress update another update is currently in progress

Tags: updates

I use plugin "Fix Another Update In Progress" and i see database wp_options table and it doesn't have core_updater_lock. This two metode doesnt work for me.. Please help

```
[21-Jun-2020 19:26:58 UTC] Creating lock core_updater.lock
[21-Jun-2020 19:26:58 UTC] lock_result = 0
[21-Jun-2020 19:26:58 UTC] lock_result = 
[21-Jun-2020 19:26:58 UTC] no lock and lock could not be created
```

Comment: It's `core_updater.lock`, with a dot not an underscore, but that is where this error comes from: it only checks the lock.

Comment: wrote incorrectly ... what's the difference, it still doesn't work

Comment: Actually I guess there is another option: you don't have permission to make a new row in wp_options? (Or it's being rejected by some DB trigger?) OK, then you need to debug these two places: [Core_Upgrader](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-admin/includes/class-core-upgrader.php#L118), which checks the lock and generates the error, and [WP_Upgrader create_lock](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L885). I'd start by adding error_log() calls just before the two `return false`s to see which is being hit.

Comment: did not quite understand what needs to be done

Comment: Modify your create_lock function to look like this: https://gist.github.com/RupW/ee7be1ae8f8da5b6b37e942283879398 All of the error_log lines are new but the rest should be the same. Then try to update again and check your server or PHP error log to see what happened.

Comment: it's not help me :(

Comment: No, this wouldn’t fix it but it’d show us what’s going on. Can you edit the trace from the error log into the question please?

Comment: it's display me in log file this "no lock and lock could not be created"

Comment: Can you try running this SQL on the database, ideally logged in as the user that WordPress uses? `INSERT INTO wp_options ( option_name, option_value, autoload ) VALUES ('core_updater.lock', 1592768373, 'no')` Hopefully there'll be a useful error message.

Comment: Ok , i do it... What should I do next? Anyway, such a mistake
[21-Jun-2020 19:52:10 UTC] Creating lock core_updater.lock
[21-Jun-2020 19:52:10 UTC] lock_result = 0
[21-Jun-2020 19:52:10 UTC] lock_result = 1592768373
[21-Jun-2020 19:52:10 UTC] lock exists and is still valid

Comment: Oh, I wasn't expecting that to work! I thought you'd an error, because the equivalent SQL from WordPress didn't work. If I thought it'd work I'd have put an older timestamp! Maybe try deleting that row in SQL and trying again? If that goes back to the 'could not be created' error, insert a row again but with timestamp 0 instead of 1592768373 and try again.

Comment: But I'm running out of ideas. I don't know why the SQL from WordPress can't insert the row, and you didn't get an error from MySQL to give us any information.

Comment: I inserted this line into this "INSERT INTO wp_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES ('core_updater.lock', 1592768373, 'no')" then again appeared "Another update is currently in progress." I then deleted this deadline again and again the same way .. I urgently need to do this update .. what to do, I don’t know anymore :(

Comment: If you just want to run the update, delete this if statement from [wp-admin/includes/class-core-updater.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-admin/includes/class-core-upgrader.php#L120-L122). Then this update should work. Sorry, was trying to find the underlying problem! The next one might not work again.

Comment: Which `IF` do I need to remove? I am very grateful that you tried to help. I’ll try to solve the problem later, just now I need to urgently

Comment: The one highlighted in that link: `if ( ! $lock ) {` `return new WP_Error( 'locked', $this->strings['locked'] );` `}`. Or just the line with the `return` would do.

Comment: Thank you very much. The update turned out. I am very grateful to you for responding to my problem. Thank you Thank you and thanks again. Now a little later I will look for why this happens.

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying files in `wp-admin`, as a result this problem will return with the next WP update :( I'd also eliminate the fix another update in progress plugin as it complicates the question so that standard fixes can't be used

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was caused by bad import of MySQL tables in phpMyAdmin.

(I exported databases instead of only one database's content. While importing MySQL errored with "Cannot create DB" but created the tables.)

Testing `INSERT INTO wp_options ( option_name, option_value, autoload ) VALUES ('core_updater.lock', 1592768373, 'no')` (thanks @Rup) said I have a duplicate primary key.

If moving a wp installation is your issue, export the old data in a propper way (click database, then export), drop tables and import the new sql file.